# Is there any function to put some value in a pandas df column based on the presense of word in text of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supoose I have a dataframe as:

| Id | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I am good girl | NaN |
| 2 | The pizza is good | NaN |
| 3 | There are flowers in the basket | NaN |
| 4 | Black dress is good | NaN |
| 5 | Sky is looking pretty | NaN |

Now I want the result to look like:

| Id | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I am good girl | good_present |
| 2 | The pizza is good | good_present |
| 3 | There are flowers in the basket | NaN |
| 4 | Black dress is good | good_present |
| 5 | Sky is looking pretty | NaN |

So for the description, if the word 'good' is present, I want to put 'good_present' in the Value Column. Tried ways of doing it, nothing worked.
For example:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('good') == 'good_present')
```

Can someone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, need remove `==` and pass value for match `else`:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('good'), 'good_present', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other alternative, you could apply a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['I am good girl',
                                   'The pizza is good',
                                   'There are flowers in the basket',
                                   'Black dress is good',
                                   'Sky is looking pretty']})

df['Value'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda s: 'good_present' if 'good' in s else np.NaN)
```

But that's a bit less elegant than jezrael's answer.